# Iterate through object using javascript to generate table rows with table data

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The goal is to render rows with 4 columns `cell` being the `<td>`. However the object has 5 data points. How can the object be iterated over so that this will render with the `uuid` as the `value` of the buttons rendered in the 4th column? If there is another way to achieve this than below?

```
const obj = [
    {
        resident: "Lily",
        date: "05/29/2020",
        type: "Basketball Court",
        status: "approved",
        uuid: "ksjdiofjoij3i4jovoii3ni"
    },{
        resident: "Kyle",
        date: "05/30/2020",
        type: "Swimming Pool",
        status: "denied",
        uuid: "wiczoixmcie923fjffj23jij"
    }
];

const table = document.querySelector("#table");
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    let row = document.createElement("TR");
    Object.entries(obj[key]).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (k !== "uuid") {
            let cell = document.createElement("TD");
            if (k === "status") {
                cell.innerHTML = `
                    <button value="` + UUIDHERE + `"class="approve-btn">Approve</button>
                    <button value="` + UUIDHERE + `"class="deny-btn">Deny</button>`;
            } else {
                cell.innerHTML = v;
            }
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    });
    table.appendChild(row);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `uuid` property from the object first, then iterate over the *other* properties.

Also, for arrays, don't iterate over its `keys`, since they aren't being used - just iterate over the array itself with `forEach` or `for..of`.

I'd also recommend using a more informative variable name - your `obj` isn't a plain object, but an array, so call it `arr`, or `residentsArr`, or something like that, else you may cause yourself (and future readers of the script) confusion later.

```js
const residentsArr = [
    {
        resident: "Lily",
        date: "05/29/2020",
        type: "Basketball Court",
        status: "approved",
        uuid: "ksjdiofjoij3i4jovoii3ni"
    },{
        resident: "Kyle",
        date: "05/30/2020",
        type: "Swimming Pool",
        status: "denied",
        uuid: "wiczoixmcie923fjffj23jij"
    }
];
residentsArr.forEach(({ uuid, ...rest }) => {
    const row = document.createElement("TR");
    Object.entries(rest).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        const cell = document.createElement("TD");
        if (k === "status") {
            cell.innerHTML = `
                <button value="${uuid}" class="approve-btn">Approve</button>
                <button value="${uuid}" class="deny-btn">Deny</button>`;
        } else {
            cell.innerHTML = v;
        }
        row.appendChild(cell);
    });
    table.appendChild(row);
});
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```